# How to use regex to extract values from a string.(PHP)

Tags: php, regex, cakephp

I have a string like this

```
\"access_token=103782364732640461|2.ZmElnDTiZlkgXbT8e34Jrw__.3600.1281891600-10000186237005083013|yD4raWxWkDe3DLPJZIRox4H6Q_k.&expires=1281891600&secret=YF5OL_fUXItLJ3dKQpQf5w__&session_key=2.ZmElnDTiZlkgXbT8e34Jrw__.3600.1281891600-10000186237005083013&sig=a2b3fdac30d53a7cca34de924dff8440&uid=10000186237005083013\"
```

I want to extract the UID.

Comment: What is the `\"` at the start of your string? Is that a literal backslash inside a single quoted string, or should it be understood as an escaped double quote inside a double-quoted string?

Answer (score 12):

It's hard to give the best answer without more information. You could try this regular expression:

```
'/&uid=([0-9]+)/'
```

Example code:

```
$s = '\"access_token=103782364732640461|2.ZmElnDTiZlkgXbT8e34Jrw__.3600.1281891600-10000186237005083013|yD4raWxWkDe3DLPJZIRox4H6Q_k.&expires=1281891600&secret=YF5OL_fUXItLJ3dKQpQf5w__&session_key=2.ZmElnDTiZlkgXbT8e34Jrw__.3600.1281891600-10000186237005083013&sig=a2b3fdac30d53a7cca34de924dff8440&uid=10000186237005083013\"';
$matches = array();
$s = preg_match('/&uid=([0-9]+)/', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Result:

```
10000186237005083013
```

But I notice that your input string looks like part of a URL. If that is the case you might want to use [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) instead. This will correctly handle a number of special cases that the regular expression won't handle correctly.

```
$arr = array();
parse_str(trim($s, '\"'), $arr);
print_r($arr['uid']);
```